# How to convert image to .resx file in .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net

How to convert image to .resx file in .NET 4.0? Seems to be resxgen.exe is no more present with the framework toolset. Could someone let me know is there a way to achieve this via some tool not using visual studio?

Comment: You should be able to get it from the [.NET 1.1 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16217)